# Extract a value from a string in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, substring, patindex

I am trying to extract a value from a string in a table like this below,

query table,

```
query_id    value
1           type={"page":"page"}&parent_id=10&image=on&content=on
2           type={"page":"page"}&parent_id=self
3           type={"category":"contact"}
```

as you can see the parent_id is in the query and sometimes is not.

I want to extract parent_id so I get this result,

```
query_id    page_id     value
1           10          type={"page":"page"}&parent_id=10&image=on&content=on
2           self        type={"page":"page"}&parent_id=self
3           null        type={"category":"contact"}
```

I try with this query,

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING(
            value,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', value) + 8,(PATINDEX('%&%', substring(value,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', value),50)) - 9)
            ) AS INT
        ) AS page_id
FROM query
```

however I get this error,

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'INT ) AS page_id FROM query LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe I should **not** be using `PATINDEX` as I tested it with the query below,

```
SELECT 
    *,
    SUBSTRING(
            value,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', value) + 8,(PATINDEX('%&%', substring(value,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', value),50)) - 9)
            ) AS test
FROM query
```

I get this error,

```
#1305 - FUNCTION mydb.PATINDEX does not exist
```

**EDIT:**

Got my answer,

```
SELECT 
    *,
    IF(LOCATE('parent_id=', value)>0,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(value,LOCATE('parent_id=', value) + 10),'&',1),null)AS page_id
FROM query
```

Comment: And this is why people invented relation databases and normalisation. Normalise your database and the answer would have been `SELECT page_id` instead.

Answer (score 3):

INT is already used in MYSQL. Use the right syntax

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CAST(
        SUBSTRING(
            `value`,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', `value`) + 8,(PATINDEX('%&%', substring(`value`,PATINDEX('%parent_id=%', `value`),50)) - 9)
            ) AS `INT`
        ) AS `page_id`
FROM `query`
```

Comment: Yep, always escape your fieldnames **and aliases** to avoid having MySQL mix it up with a reserved name (like INT). +1

Comment: Are you using a single quote or a backtick (`)?  It needs to be the backtick.